# Lucene matching Keyword and UnIndexed options from older version

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

**Old version**

- Keyword—Isn’t analyzed, but is indexed and stored in the index
  verbatim.
- UnIndexed—Is neither analyzed nor indexed, but its value is stored in
  the  index as is.

**Newer version**

> For matching **Keyword** what would be the difference   between

```
new Field( name, value, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED )
```

and

```
new Field( name, value, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED_NO_NORMS )
```

> Matching Unindexed =

```
new Field( name, value, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NO )
```

> And finally what could be the usage of ?

```
new Field( name, value, Field.Store.NO, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between `NOT_ANALYZED` and `NOT_ANALYZED_NO_NORMS` is that one doesn't have norms.  Norms include a small amount of meta-data used in scoring hits.  This includes index-time field boost and a length norm.  If the field only has one term (as NOT_ANALYZED fields generally do), the length norm isn't really relevant.  So, if you don't need to have field boosts at index time, you can safely index with no norms, and save a byte of space per field, per document.

---

Yes,

```
new Field( name, value, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NO )
```

Would be a good way to index a stored-only, non-indexed field.

---

The usage of:

```
new Field( name, value, Field.Store.NO, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED )
```

Would be to index and make searchable the entire contents of the value without analysis, and not store the value for fetching from the index.  The Store value passed in is whether you need to be able to fetch that data from a search result.  The Index value controls how you will be able to search for it (if at all).

Not to be confused with:

```
new Field( name, value, Field.Store.NO, Field.Index.NO )
```

The usage of that is to throw an `IllegalArgumentException`.